# Adding things above and below bootstrap fixed navbar

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am trying to add a banner above my fixed-top navbar.  I have looked around and understand some basic concepts on how to do this but my example is a little more complex and I am getting a little lost.

User can add a custom banner to the top of my page.  If this happens I need to push everything (including the fixed navbar) down the height of the banner (say 20 px).

I have created a class that I can apply to the nav element:

```
.top-banner-nav {
  top: 20px;
}
```

Navbar:

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" ng-class="{'top-banner-nav': banner == true}">
```

That works great to push the static navbar down 20px if there is a banner.  However I have to problems.

1. When you have a static navbar like this you have to add a top padding to the body to push the body content below the banner.  Now all of the sudden I would need to push the body content down 70px.  Not sure if there is a good way to make this happen dynamically.
2. I have another static navbar directly underneath the very top navbar.  When I move the very top navbar down 20px I need to move this other navbar down 20px as well.  Unfortunately this lower nav is fixed as well with top: 50px to place it right below the upper navbar.

I have a plunker here that demonstrates the problem.  And I am not really sure where to go from here.  Might have to mess with things in javascript, but I would like to try and avoid that is at all possible to avoid things jumping around on page load.

http://plnkr.co/edit/DYYMz1?p=preview

Answer (score 4):

I looked at your plunker. I made some changes to your CSS and HTML to accomplish what you are looking for.  The change I made to the HTML was the body tag.  The new tag looks like this:

```
<body ng-controller="MainController" ng-class="{'bodyModified': banner == true}">
```

The new CSS file looks like this:

```
body {
  padding-top: 50px; Need this to move down body under fixed header
}

.bodyModified {
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.settings-nav {
    position: relative;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #E2E2E2;
    z-index: 1029;
    top:0px;
}

.settings-content {
    padding-top: 70px;
}

.top-banner-nav {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    height: 20px;
}

.top-banner {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    top:0;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    background-color: #FFFF00;
}
```

You can also use javascript and jQuery to accomplish this as well.  Hope that helps.  Let me know how it goes.

Here is a plunker demonstrating the changes

http://plnkr.co/edit/39LhQA2gdMremnTOGXe4?p=preview

Comment: Banner height is not 20px in this example.

Comment: @lostintranslation initially I had it set to auto which worked fine.  I changed it to 20px in my answer.  It still gives you the same result.  Is it working for you?

Comment: I also added a plunker demonstrating the changes. @lostintranslation

Comment: banner at top causes fixed navbar to scroll.

Answer (score 0):

you can try jquery solution for this.for example if you are using `top-nav-fixed-banner` class you can code something like this.

```
function fixBannerHeight(){
    var bannerHeight = $(".top-banner-div").height();
    $(".top-nav-fixed-banner").each(function(e){
          var height = $(this).height();
          bannerHeight = bannerHeight  + height;                
    })
    $('.top-banner-div').css({"height":bannerHeight+"px"});
}
```

call `fixBannerHeight()` when you are adding dynamically banner.

Hope this helps.